# Error in React app: window.functionFromThirdParty is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-hooks, window

From a third party I have to add a function to the window object:

In my React child component I added it like:

```
useEffect(() => {
   window.functionFromThirdParty();
  }, [id]);
```

But then I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: window.functionFromThirdParty is not a function

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the function is actually being added to the window object by the third party code. You can check this by running `console.log(window)` in the browser's developer console and seeing if the function is listed.

Answer (score 0):

It is either related to third party conflict, or you did not import that function properly, could you try to give us more info and specifically where you imported it into window object.